# Postgres: jsonb to jsonb[]?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have this table:

```
ams=# \d player
                               Table "public.player"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id          | integer                  |           | not null |
 created     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 player_info | jsonb                    |           | not null |
```

And then I have this:

```
ams=# \d report
                        Table "public.report"
 Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id      | integer                  |           | not null |
 created | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 data    | jsonb[]                  |           | not null |
```

How can I take the `player_info` from all the rows in the `player` table and insert that into a single row in the `report` table (into the `data` `jsonb[]` field)? My attempts with `jsonb_agg()` return a `jsonb`, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to go from `jsonb` to `jsonb[]`. Any pointers would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. Use `jsonb` as well and create a json array instead of an array of json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plainly want to copy the values, just treat it like any other data type, and use `ARRAY_AGG`.

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(player_info)
FROM player
WHERE id IN (...)
```

should return something of type `json[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `jsonb[]` is an array at the type level in PostgreSQL vs. a json array, use `array_agg()` instead of `jsonb_agg()`.

```
insert into report 
select 1 as id, now() as created, array_agg(player_info)
  from player
;
```

Comment: Thank you. Ruben beat your answer by 10ms so I had to chose his answer :)